# Returning a list in this recursive coi function in python

Tags: python, list, recursion

I'm having trouble getting my list to return in my code.  Instead of returning the list, it keeps returning None, but if I replace the return with print in the elif statement, it prints the list just fine.  How can I repair this?

```
def makeChange2(amount, coinDenomination, listofcoins = None):
#makes a list of coins from an amount given by using a greedy algorithm
    coinDenomination.sort()
    #reverse the list to make the largest position 0 at all times
    coinDenomination.reverse()
    #assigns list
    if listofcoins is None:
        listofcoins = []
    if amount >= coinDenomination[0]:
        listofcoins = listofcoins + [coinDenomination[0]]
        makeChange2((amount - coinDenomination[0]), coinDenomination, listofcoins)
    elif amount == 0:
        return listofcoins
    else:

        makeChange2(amount, coinDenomination[1:], listofcoins)
```

Comment: Nate, Mark Rushakoff answered your question; you should accept his answer. You can do that by clicking on the check mark (✓) under the vote count of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're not `return`ing the value of the recursive calls to `makeChange2`.

Once control reaches either of those calls to `makeChange2` and completes the call, the program continues to the next statement, which is the end of the function; thus, it returns `None`.

If that concept is still giving you trouble, try running this simple factorial program with and without the `return` keyword in the `return n*factorial(n-1)` line:

```
def factorial(n):
   if n == 0 or n == 1:
       return 1
   return n * factorial(n-1)

print factorial(3)
```

Manually walking through the code should help elucidate what was wrong in your original program.

Comment: I don't get it still.  How is it returning to the end of the function if amount always goes to 0?  It shouldn't reach the end of the function.  Also, I have walked through this bloody thing for 10 hours.  Trust me, I only ask places like this as a last resort.  I'm stumped, and I simply do not know what to do.  Also, adding return does not work:

        return makeChange2((amount - coinDenomination[0]), coinDenomination, listofcoins)
    elif amount == 0:
        return listofcoins

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you are saying now.  I have to return in both if and else statements, or it goes to the end of the list in every call except the last.  Thankyou for your help.